# Generate PDF from HTML without buttons

Tags: html, css, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

I use to generate pdf from my web page wkhtmltopdf.

My project is on ASP.Net and on Bootstrap. So buttons on page has common classes `btn btn-primary`.

As i know if i set to some element `.Visible = false;` this element will be invisible on pdf. As there are many buttons on page it isn't too nice to set visibility to each button by `Id`.

So how can i get all buttons from page just by className?

What i found :

In some post on Stack user advice to add event  `OnPreRender` and in this event set visibility to false. Example:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkContinue" runat="server" OnClick="lnkContinue_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Continue" OnPreRender="Button_PreRender"></asp:LinkButton>

protected void Button_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var button = (HtmlGenericControl)sender;
            button.Visible = !button.Attributes.CssStyle.Value.Contains("btn btn-primary");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply your own javascript function to wkhtmltopdf to iterate over each element and make them invisible:

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

--run-script js

```
var eles = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary');
for (var x = 0; x < eles.length; x++) {
    eles[x].style.visibility = false;
}
```

Comment: can you provide how to use wkhtmltopdf scripts?

Comment: See the documentation I linked, the --run-script argument allows you to pass in a javascript snippet as a piece of code to execute before converting to pdf.
As in:
wkhtmltopdf --run-script "var eles = document.getElementById('btn')......" url

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly use the HTML generated for your webpage as the HTML for the PDF. Your webpage will likely have navigation and other UI elements (like the mentioned buttons) that aren't appropriate for display in the PDF.

A better solution is to separately generate the HTML. This allows you to retain control over the exact markup used to create the PDF. You can manually build the HTML with [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) or use other libraries to create it.

My favorite way of doing this is using the [Razor PDF for MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF) library. You use Razor syntax (which is very intuitive) to generate a PDF.

Comment: i remove all links from html, maybe in not very elegant way